# Node instalação sem npm apenas via .zip

Tags: node.js

Preciso instalar um modulo nodejs em um servidor e ele não tem acesso a internet. se baixo ele no github, como instalar ele no servidor?

Não quero usar npm install para fazer o download diretamente da internet

Comment: conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Na pasta que você baixou o Node.js execute:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/node && make && sudo make install
```

Para facilitar os comandos do node adicione o caminho do node em um desses arquivos:

`~/.profile` ou `~/.bash_profile` ou `~/.bashrc` ou `~/.zshenv`

Procure um deles edite com `sudo nano` ou `sudo vim` e adicione a linha:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node/bin
```

Fonte: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation